# Can't save value from session in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, session-variables

I am trying to store  payer_id and total_price inside database that I have stored in session. When I echo them out they do show on the screen but when the same way I try to create a record it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
echo (int)session()->get('quantity') * (int)session()->get('pc_cost');
echo session()->get('paypal_payment_id');
```

These above lines do work just fine, but when I do the following

```
$price = (int)session()->get('quantity') * (int)session()->get('pc_cost');
$payer_id = session()->get('paypal_payment_id');
$order = Order::create([
    'user_id' => Auth::User()->id,
    'ordered_pc_id' => $ordered->id,
    'total_price' => $price,
    'deadline' => session()->get('expected'),
    'quantity' => session()->get('quantity'),
    'payer_id' => $payer_id,
    'status' => 0,
    'notes' => session()->get('notes'),
]);
```

I have also checked my datatypes in database, it's integer for total_price and varchar(255) for payer_id. Could you help me with this please ?

Comment: all other values are working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a default Eloquent models protect against mass assignment. You values may not set in your `Model::create()` call because of this behaviour.

You can the attributes that may be mass assigned on your model using the `$fillable` attribute like this:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'ordered_pc_id',
        'total_price',
        'deadline',
        'quantity',
        'payer_id',
        'status',
        'notes',
    ];
}
```

See further details in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

Do you have this set up in your model for all attributes?

Comment: yup,, your are right, I forgot to add them inside the model. Shame I couldn't figure it out sooner. Thanks @haakym.

Comment: Although, 1 thing I couldn't figure out is why didn't it throw a mass assignment exception ?

Comment: After it happens a few times you always remember to check lol. Glad it's working for you now. That's a good point, I don't know!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use **forceCreate()** that allow mass-assignment:

```
$order = Order::forceCreate([
    'user_id' => Auth::User()->id,
    'ordered_pc_id' => $ordered->id,
    'total_price' => $price,
    'deadline' => session()->get('expected'),
    'quantity' => session()->get('quantity'),
    'payer_id' => $payer_id,
    'status' => 0,
    'notes' => session()->get('notes'),
]);
```